# Jquery - how to inject an event handler from embedded iframe into parent DOM elements

Tags: jquery

New to jquery and trying to get injection working. Any help appreciated.

I have an iframe embedded into a parent page.  From within the iframe (where I instantiate jquery) I wish to inject an 'onmouseover' event handler to all DOM elements of class = "btn" in that parent page. All of these elements are in div levels within a top level container div with id = "contentWrapper"

Am assuming it'll be something like the following, but any tips really welcomed to point me in the right direction.

```
// am assuming I can see <div id='contentWrapper'> element in parent frame from within the iframe
// not sure where to place the 'btn' class reference.

$('contentWrapper').on('onmouseover', function(event){ 
     // some activity here 
});
```

Comment: Are they on the same domain?

Comment: nope - not same domain. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 parent.find('#contentWrapper .btn').on('onmouseover', function(event){ 
 // some activity here 
});
```

Comment: this'll sound stupid, but what do I append the parent.find to?  if my iframe is id = 'iframe' would I use $('iframe').parent.find(... ? this also doesnt filter to class="btn".

Comment: jus call this in you iframe script.. no need to attach anything.. `parent` will take u to parent page... and `find` will get you the button

Comment: Hey thanks bipen for your help - i did get a cross domain scripting issue when I tried parent so that wont work unfortunately as my same domain answer was incorrect - that said, I think it might be possible to get from iframe up to parent DOM using jquery somehow, but led you down garden path here sorry - thanks again for your help.